# asp:Login with LayoutTemplate creates persistent cookie regardless whether remember me is checked

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using .NET 4 and the asp.net login control with a custom layout template when I sign in, regardless whether the remember me checkbox is checked or not, the control seems to create an authentication cookie and keep me signed in until I explicitly sign out by clicking a sign out button. Closing the browser while still signed in does not sign me out.

Can someone help explain what might be causing this?

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnLoggingIn="Login1_LoggingIn" OnLoggedIn="Login1_LoggedIn" OnLoginError="Login1_LoginError">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="btnLogin">
            <label>Email</label>&nbsp;<div class="required">*</div>&nbsp;
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required" InitialValue="" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="Login" /><br />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" class="input" ValidationGroup="Login" />
            <label>Password</label>&nbsp;<div class="required">*</div>&nbsp;
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required" InitialValue="" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="Login" /><br />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" class="input" style="margin:0 0 6px 0;" ValidationGroup="Login" />
            <asp:Checkbox runat="server" ID="RememberMe" Text="Remember me" CssClass="remember-me" />
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnLogin" CommandName="Login" Text="Sign In" CssClass="login-button" ValidationGroup="Login" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>


protected void Login1_LoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
    string username = Login1.UserName.Trim();

    if (IsValid)
    { 
        MembershipUser user1 = Membership.GetUser(username);
        if (user1 != null)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(user1.UserName, Login1.Password))
            { 
                Login1.UserName = user1.UserName;
            }
        }
    }


protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "Users"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("users.aspx", true);
    }

<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms timeout="129600" name=".AUTHCOOKIE" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" path="/" requireSSL="false" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got your answer... geez finally!

Login.aspx:

```
    <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnLoggingIn="Login1_LoggingIn">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="btnLogin">
                <label>Email</label>&nbsp;<div class="required">*</div>
                &nbsp;
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required" InitialValue="" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="Login" /><br />
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" class="input" ValidationGroup="Login" />
                <label>Password</label>&nbsp;<div class="required">*</div>
                &nbsp;
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required" InitialValue="" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="Login" /><br />
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" class="input" Style="margin: 0 0 6px 0;" ValidationGroup="Login" />
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="RememberMe" Text="Remember me" CssClass="remember-me" />
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnLogin" CommandName="Login" Text="Sign In" CssClass="login-button" ValidationGroup="Login" />
            </asp:Panel>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:Login>
```

Login.aspx.cs

```
protected void Login1_LoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValid)
    {
        if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms timeout="129600" name=".AUTHCOOKIE" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" path="/" requireSSL="false" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies">
        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
            <user name="test" password="test"/>
        </credentials>
    </forms>
</authentication>
```

Additional Notes:

In my web application, I have a folder called "Protected" and a file inside called "Users.aspx" and another file called Web.Config. The web.config inside of the "Protected" folder has the following to not allow anonymous users and only allow the "test" user:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
            <allow users="test"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I closed all my chrome instances after logging in, then went to the users.aspx page, and surely enough, was asked to log in again! I know this code isn't exactly what you have but you should be able to modify your code to adopt this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that's not working. I added the RedirectFromLoginPage() inside the if (Membership.ValidateUser()) and after successfully logging in with remember me unchecked I close the browser window then return to the website and I'm still logged in. This is on our testing server, not localhost.

Comment: Did you close the entire browser or just the tab? Because I tried closing the entire browser and all instances and it worked for me... hmm.... let me see if I can come up with something else.

Comment: This is where I got the answer from and it's working for him: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715873/asp-net-forms-authentication-cookie-not-expiring/2716020#2716020

Comment: Ok try this: FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);

Comment: Another thing I would do is check the auth cookie's expiration date.

Comment: Nope. Still staying logged in. I'm closing the whole window.

Comment: Using firebug the auth cookie's expiration is set to 'session' so it shouldn't be logging me back in when I close the browser window. And when I change it to FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true) the cookie's expiration is still set to session.

Comment: I think this might have something to do with your web.config settings... let me try and get an environment up and running and I'll mess with your code and get back to you

Comment: Please look at my answer, I just **edited it**. I just tested it and it works :). Sorry for the back and forth :-/

Comment: Sorry, still not working. I don't fully understand this code as FormsAuthentication.Authenticate() always returns false and yet my custom Membership provider Membership.Validate() that I'm overriding still fires and returns true logging me in. But in either case, when I close the browser and return I'm still logged in.